# Reordering algorithm via iterated rotate

Tags: c++, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Consider a dataset with `N` samples, where every sample consists of `head` elements followed by `tail` elements. I'd like to perform an stable reordering such that `N` `tails` are grouped together at the top, and `N` `heads` are grouped together at the bottom.

For example, the dataset:

```
 -1  -2  -3   1   2   3   4   5
 -4  -5  -6   6   7   8   9  10
 -7  -8  -9  11  12  13  14  15
-10 -11 -12  16  17  18  19  20
```

has has `N = 4` samples, with `head = 3` (negative integers), and `tail = 5` (positive integers). The desired transformation would yield:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
 17  18  19  20  -1  -2  -3  -4
 -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10 -11 -12
```

I implemented a solution based on repeated application of rotations. The rotations are those implemented by the C++ algorithm [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

> `std::rotate(first, n_first, last)` swaps the elements in the range
>   `[first, last)` in such a way that the element `n_first` becomes the
>   first element of the new range and `n_first - 1` becomes the last
>   element.

My implementation (shown below) provides a correct solution and performs well for my problems. However, it needs to perform `N` rotations, where the complexity of every rotation increases from `O(head + tail)` to `O(N * tail + head)`.

**Are you aware of an algorithm with better complexity?**.

My code follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename I> // I models Forward Iterator
I reorder(I f, I l, std::size_t head_size, std::size_t tail_size)
{
  std::size_t k = 1;
  auto m = std::next(f, head_size);
  auto t = std::next(m, tail_size);
  while (t != l) {
    f = std::rotate(f, m, std::next(m, tail_size));
    m = std::next(f, ++k * head_size);
    t = std::next(m, tail_size);
  };
  return std::rotate(f, m, t);
}

template <typename C>
void show(const char* message, const C& c)
{
  std::size_t shown { 0 };
  std::cout << message << "\n";
  for (auto && ci : c)
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << ci
              << (++shown % 8 == 0 ? "\n" : " ");
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v {
    -1,  -2,  -3,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
    -4,  -5,  -6,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
    -7,  -8,  -9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
   -10, -11, -12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

  std::size_t head_size { 3 };
  std::size_t tail_size { 5 };

  show("before reorder", v);

  reorder(v.begin(), v.end(), head_size, tail_size);

  show("after reorder", v);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ clang++ example.cpp -std=c++14
before reorder
 -1  -2  -3   1   2   3   4   5
 -4  -5  -6   6   7   8   9  10
 -7  -8  -9  11  12  13  14  15
-10 -11 -12  16  17  18  19  20
after reorder
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
 17  18  19  20  -1  -2  -3  -4
 -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10 -11 -12
```

### Details about the problem domain

I'm reading images where every *line* is preceded by pixel metadata, and followed by the raw pixels, like so:

```
[metadata] [pixels...]
[metadata] [pixels...]
[ many more of these]
[metadata] [pixels...]
```

I need to pack all the pixels together and pass them to OpenGL, but I also need to maintain the metadata accessible for the program. So, I do this:

```
 [all the pixels] [all the metadata]
```

and pass `[all the pixels]` to my graphics card while keeping a handle to `[all the metadata]` in the CPU.

### Edit

Thanks for your responses - I've ended up implementing an alternative solution that does not rely on reordering. However, the point remains: can you improve the algorithm for "in place" dataset reordering? It is similar to *in place matrix transpose*.

Comment: Are metadata and pixel chunks sizes known in advance? If yes not simply mem copy those?

Answer (score 2):

One very fast solution is to create another matrix and place elements directly where they belong.

For example, say you have n rows, t tails and h heads. The first tail on the first row (1, 1) is going to ( (h * n+1)/(h+t), (h * n+1)%(h+t)). I will let you formulate for the general case (i,j) going to (k,l). In any case, it's a calculation involving integer division and modulus.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the input format:

```
[metadata] [pixels...]
[metadata] [pixels...]
[ many more of these]
[metadata] [pixels...]
```

What you should do is to read these directly into the structure you need, which as far as I can see are two: contiguous pixels and contiguous metadata.  So:

```
std::vector<Pixel> pixels;
std::vector<Metadata> meta;
// maybe reserve() a reasonable amount based on input size

// for each record in input:
    pixels.push_back(...);
    meta.push_back(...);
```

Now you have one vector with all the pixel data to pass to the GPU, and one with all the metadata for yourself.  No need to copy memory around.

Comment: That's how I ended up implementing it - but I'm still curious about an effective algorithm for reordering (similar to "in memory matrix transpose").